# Как в сущности Entity Framework хранить только дату из БД без времени?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, entity

Для того, чтобы в gridData отобразить только дату, в поле сущности нужно хранить только дату.
В БД mysql данное поле имет тип "DATA", но в сущность подгружается как DataTime и содержит и выводит в gridData и дату и время. Мне нужна только дата.

Я пытался решить эту проблему с помощью аннотации:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class man
    {

        private int Id_Man { get; set; }
        private string _FIO;
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        private DateTime _Birthday;
        private Nullable<double> _Height;
        private Nullable<double> _Weight;
}
```

Но это не дало результат.
Пытался писать get set, чтобы они отдавали и устанавливали нужный формат, но это тоже не помогло:

```
public partial class man
    {

        private int Id_Man { get; set; }
        private string _FIO;
        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        private DateTime _Birthday;
        private Nullable<double> _Height;
        private Nullable<double> _Weight;


        public DateTime Birthday
        {
            get { return _Birthday.Date; }
            set
            {
                if (this._Birthday == value) return;
                this._Birthday = value.Date;
                onPropertyChanged("Birthday");
            }
        }
}
```

Подскажите как можно сделать?

Comment: Задайте формат вывода в гриде.

Comment: Сработало. Спасибо!